# Showing JSON data from DB to django template using Bootstrap tabs

Tags: python, html, css, django, bootstrap-4

Sorry I'm a programming newb.... 
But I am trying to use Bootstrap's tabs navigation to view JSON data from a DB. I'm transforming the JSON data to a 2d array and storing my data as the following dictionary:

```
tables = {u'table1': [[u'CS6140', u'Machine Learning', u'Sara 
                     Arunagiri'], [u'CS5100', u'Foundations of 
                     Artificial Intelligence ', u'Chris Amato'], 
                     [u'CS6220', u'Data Mining', u'Pablo Esteves']], 
          u'table2': [[u'Paris, France', u'06/01/2019 - 06/15/2019', 
                     u'James Fraser'], [u'Edinborough, Scotland', 
                     u'10/14/2019 - 10/20/2019', u'Claire  Beauchamp'], 
                     [u'Rome, Italy', u'12/14/2019-12/24/2019', 
                     u'Timothy Dalton']], 
          u'table3': [[32423, u'iced coffee', 3.67], [34241, u'bagel', 
                     2.99], [3109247, u'sanwich', 5.99]]}
```

Thus each table dict entry corresponds to one table.So I'm trying to loop through the dictionary and 2d array to create different tables.

I'm currently trying to loop through the dictionary as follows but I am getting the 2d arrays replicated 3 times for each of the tables when instead I want each table in my dictionary to only be shown once for each tab.

```
            {% for table in tables %}
            <div class="tab-content">

                <div id="{{ table }}" class="tab-pane active">
                    {% for table in tables.values %}
                    <table class="table">
                        <tbody>
                        {% for row in table %}
                        <tr>
                            {% for item in row %}
                            <td>{{ item }}</td>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
```

I'm hoping for some insight on to how else store or pass the data to my context to get what I want i.e.

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="table1" class="tab-pane active">
          <table class="table">...</table>
    </div>
    <div id="table2" class="tab-pane active">
          <table class="table">...</table>
    </div>
    <div id="table3" class="tab-pane active">
          <table class="table">...</table>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

vs. what I'm currently getting:

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="table1" class="tab-pane active">
             <table class="table">...</table>
             <table class="table">...</table>
             <table class="table">...</table>
    </div>
    <div id="table2" class="tab-pane active">
             <table class="table">...</table>
             <table class="table">...</table>
             <table class="table">...</table>
    </div>
    <div id="table3" class="tab-pane active">
             <table class="table">...</table>
             <table class="table">...</table>
             <table class="table">...</table>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```html
<div class="tab-content">
    {% for table_name, table in tables.items %}
        <div id="{{ table_name }}" class="tab-pane {% if forloop.first %} active {% endif %}">
            <table class="table">
                <tbody>
                    {% for row in table %}
                        <tr>
                        {% for item in row %}
                            <td>{{ item }}</td>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

It's better to use your keys and values of your dictionary using `.items` at the beginning of your loop, rather than getting your values further down your loop logic. It avoids confusion in your loop logic.

**EDIT:**
The `active` class should only be for the first tab. Thus, you need to use the `forloop.first` template tag to add the class thr first time you run through the loop.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, changing the loop as you stated did work! Except that for the initial rendering, the first tab still shows all 3 tables, it's not until I click through all the tabs that the appropriate table data shows up in each respective tab, any chance you may have any ideas as to why that's happening?

Comment: It's because all the tabs had the `active` class. See my edit for the fix.